# Convert spark sql to python spark / Databricks pipeline event logs

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, event-log, databricks-sql

I have the following sql statement to query the databricks pipeline event logs and it works.
I tried to rewrite it into a python code, but I failed.

Could somebody provide me any advice? Many thanks!!

```sql
SELECT timestamp, details:user_action:action, details:user_action:user_name
FROM event_log_raw 
WHERE event_type = 'user_action'
```

**Please Note** the details column here is **string** type, not struct nor array

The following solutions I tried didn't work 
`df` is a spark dataFrame generated from the table `event_log_raw`

```py
df.filter(df.event_type == 'user_action').select("timestamp", "details:user_action:action", "details:user_action:user_name")
```

```py
df.filter(df.event_type == 'user_action').select("timestamp", "details.user_action.action", "details.user_action.user_name")
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `select` you need to use `selectExpr` because the string like `details:user_action:action` is a JSON path expression for extracting data from the JSON string ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-json-path-expression.html)):

```py
df.filter(df.event_type == 'user_action')
  .selectExpr("timestamp", "details:user_action:action", "details:user_action:user_name")
```